# Detect and store various date format

Tags: php, date

I have to build a PHP script that can manage an input date then convert it in a particular format (in order to save it in a MySQL database) and finally output a second date in the same format as the input.

For example :

I receive a date `2013-09-01`, I convert it into `2013-09-01 00:00:00` and I store it in MySQL.
Then, some days later, I have to output a new date (the input date +2 days for example) in the original format, `2013-09-03` in this case.

Input dates can be in various format such like:

> 2013-09-29
>
> 2013-09-01 23:20:05
>
> 2013-09-16T11:32:01+00:00
>
> 2013-09-18T13:20:02.000Z
>
> 2013-09-09T15:16:02

I think I have to detect the input date format, store it, the convert the date to the internal date storage, and finally build a new date with the original format.

My problem is that I have no idea how to detect the input date format and normalize it in order to use it later.

Does anybody have a trick for me ?

Thanks

EDIT: I don't need a solution anymore, the API service sent me an exhaustive list of input date format, so I'm going to use regex.

Comment: You may try strtotime function

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not allowing people to put in whatever date format they want.  I think it might be impossible, but it would be very difficult to determine the date correctly!  What happens if they put in '2013-01-02', is that January 2nd or 1st Feb??

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend not allowing people to put in whatever date format they want.  I think it would be very difficult to determine the date or date format correctly if you're giving people free reign on how they input the date!

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can be used to convert a string to a UNIX timestamp ready to be stored - but it's not a miracle function! It won't 'tell' you what format the user entered their date in as so that it can be unravelled and shown back and it won't accept **any** date format.

What happens if they put in '2013-01-02', is that January 2nd or 1st Feb?  How are you going to 'store' the original date format, it's not going to be possible without a lot of work and even then you couldn't exhaust all possible date formats unless you've got a lot of time on your hands.

The only reasonable way is to adapt your input form to accept only date formats that you expect, store them in the database in a standard format along with your pre-determined date formats and then show them on the page in your predetermined date formats using [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert it from the UNIX timestamp into something readable.

Comment: Actually this is not my choice, I have to implement an API that just works this way. They send me date in various format, then I have to send back (some days later) a new date in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime). It's not a magical function though so it wont accept *any* format. For instance how do you distinguish dd-mm-yyyy vs mm-dd-yyyy? (strtotime assumes dd-mm-yyyy)

If your formats are what you gave, and you just want the date you can always just:

```
$date = substr($date, 0, 10);
```

Or is that too clever? :P

Comment: Yep, that's works for storing inputs dates in the same format, but I don't know how to determine what format is astually used in order to send back (some days later) a new date in the original format.

`echo strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", strtotime('2013-09-29')).'<br/>';
echo strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", strtotime('2013-09-01 23:20:05')).'<br/>';
echo strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", strtotime('2013-09-16T11:32:01+00:00')).'<br/>';
echo strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", strtotime('2013-09-18T13:20:02.000Z')).'<br/>';
echo strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", strtotime('2013-09-09T15:16:02')).'<br/>';`